# What would cause this JPA Calendar query to break when migrating from JPA1.0 to JPA2.0?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I just migrated an app from JPA1.0/Hibernate 3.3.2.GA to JPA2.0/Hibernate 3.6.10.FINAL and one of my existing JPA queries no longer works.

The query uses a constrain on the value of a persistent field that looks like this:

```
private java.sql.Timestamp birthday;
```

And the query looks like this:

```
String qlString = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.birthday BETWEEN :minDate AND :maxDate";
Query query = eMgrTwo.createQuery(qlString);

Calendar minDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
minDateCalendar.set(1970, 4, 29);

Calendar maxDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
maxDateCalendar.set(1970, 6, 29);

query.setParameter("minDate", minDateCalendar, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
query.setParameter("maxDate", maxDateCalendar, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

List results = query.getResultList();
```

Agains the older versions of jpa and hibernate, this works.  Against, the newer versions, I get an error complaining that the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [java.util.GregorianCalendar SNIP SNIP] did not match expected type [java.util.Date]
```

If I change my code to use Date instead of Calendar, it works.  I just want to know why the previous code worked?  Did the API change?  Or were we previously using an undocumented feature?

Comment: I guess no one else saw this . . . at any rate, there is this migration issue.